# d3.js scatterplot matrix cars dataset

Tags: d3.js, visualization, scatter-plot

I used d3.js to visualize cars dataset (http://infovis.sjolie.se/data/?file=cars.csv)  in scatterplot matrix. I tried to use Mike Bostock's example but something went wrong with my result. Can anybody help me? I'm very new in d3.js [scatters are out of the graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRczb.png)

Comment: can you add information about the error and what you expect as a result?

Comment: can you put your code here? particularly the scales, `x.domain()`, `x.range()`, etc.

Comment: i've used this example https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063663, basically i only changed dataset (d3.csv("cars.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
) and traits name( var domainByTrait = {},
      traits = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(d) { return d !== "name"; }),
      n = traits.length;)

Comment: @ozkary i expect something like this http://se.mathworks.com/help/stats/examples/visualizing-multivariate-data.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by your picture, your scales are all messed up.  My WAG is that they aren't being cast to numeric data and instead are being treated as ordinal scales.  You can fix this by forcing the cast with an [accessor](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#csv) function:

```
d3.csv("cars.csv", function(d) {
    return {
      name: d["name"],
      economy: +d["economy (mpg)"],
      cylinders: +d["cylinders"],
      displacement: +d["displacement (cc)"],
      power: +d["power (hp)"],
      year: +d["year"]
    };
  }, function(error, data) {

  ....
```

[Here's some working code](http://plnkr.co/edit/r9lS72WpbhTgb1oC2bWQ?p=preview).